# RStudio Package Check fails, uses cached, removed information

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to build a toy package that depends on other packages.  My current package builds and I can `library()` load the package, run the sole function, and it works fine.  However, when I run 'Check' on the package (within RStudio), I get an error result on a package dependency `jsonlite`, which I don't have in my code.  I had previously, but deleted it, and did a clean and rebuild from the gui.  Here is the output of `Check`:

```
── R CMD check results ──────────────────────────────── hydrocracking 0.1.0 ────
Duration: 11.9s

❯ checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  Namespace dependency not required: ‘jsonlite’

  See section ‘The DESCRIPTION file’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’
  manual.
```

Where would this be cached?  Here is the current state of my 3 important files, as I understand it:

R/hello.R:

```
#' Main call
#'
#' Main call to create sqrt call
#'
#' @param x Number to take sqrt of
#'
#' @return Number
#'
#' @import tidyverse
#'
#' @export
hello <- function(x) {
  x %>% sqrt()
}
```

DESCRIPTION:

```
Package: hydrocracking
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: me
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
Depends:
    tidyverse
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.0
```

NAMESPACE:

```
# Generated by roxygen: do not edit by hand

export(hello)
import(tidyverse)
```

Again, the package loads, and the function call works... I just don't understand the `Check` failure:

```
library(hydrocracking)
hello(2)
#>[1] 1.414214
```

Comment: How did you initially set up the package? With `devtools::create()`? Have you tried quitting RStudio, restarting it, and then running `check()`?

Comment: Hi @duckmayr -- I set it up using the package wizard via RStudio.  But a full RStuido restart seems to have fixed it.  Will post solution and reference you, thanks.

Comment: This was specifically an RStudio issue, please mark it as such. Quitting and restarting should always be the second thing you try, esp. when you suspect RStudio rather than the underlying R command.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the whole RStuidio GUI solved it.

I thought restarting the session within the GUI was enough, but that was incorrect.

Thanks to @duckmayr for suggestion.